# Changing or adding prefix for Ejabberd Database tables

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-auth

Is there any possibility to change or add a prefix for user table in Ejabberd database.

My requirement is, I want to user authentication ( using php ) via my own database ( pgsql ). Using external auth settings I have managed to do that. Same as I would like to save all my chat related data on that same DB. ( Not saving inside Ejabberd ). But I already have a user credential table, unfortunately it is not "users" and I can not change it.

I am thinking if I will change the Ejabberd "users" table reference into my DB's user data table name, I could use "external" database settings for authenticate and storing.

If I need to do some changes and rebuild the source code, where and what are the correct changes I should add or update into source code. I try to understand with reading the Ejabberd source base but I could not find any clue ( Of course I am newby to Erlang and Ejabberd )

If anybody has good sofisticate idea or solution please update me.

Answer (score 0):

> But I already have a user credential table, unfortunately it is not "users" and I can not change it.

Then you will have to use "external" auth https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#external-script

Comment: That is what I am using.

@Badlop I am using "external" auth ( extauth_program: some php file connect with my DB as document explaining ) . And I am using "sql_type" as my DB with ejabberd database schema. but once I change the table name, client can not authenticate. And when I create users it won't show in Admin section. where  I went wrong ?